Java EWS AppointmentSchema.Recurrence content does not appear
I personally confirmed that the schedule was repetitive, and confirmed that the schedule's repetition information was displayed in the web version created in C#.
However, I am refactoring to Java, and the schedule's repetition information does not appear.
I invested a lot of time and I don't know.
I ask for wisdom
ExchangeService service = ewsUtil.getEws();
FolderId calendarFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(dtEndDateTime);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
dtEndDateTime = calendar.getTime();
CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(dtStartDateTime, dtEndDateTime);
cView.setPropertySet(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties));

FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = service.findAppointments(calendarFolderId, cView);

for (Appointment appointment : findResults) {
   ItemId itemId = appointment.getId();
   PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
   propertySet.add(AppointmentSchema.Recurrence);
   Appointment fullAppointment = Appointment.bind(service, itemId, propertySet);
   fullAppointment.getRecurrence()    // -> null!!!!!
}

Exchange version is Exchange2010_SP2.
